# Passport validity is less than 6 month on departure date

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, passports, india, visa-expiration

I plan to travel to India on Jan 30, 2021, with a green card valid until Dec 18, 2029, and an Indian Passport valid until April 4, 2021.
Will there be an issue with my passport to travel to India?

I shall be returning to the USA on June 30, 2021, with a renewed passport and valid green card.
Will there be an issue with my travel or passport?